# JQuery Tablesorter Add Column with Filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am using JQuery Tablesorter 2.7.* for a JavaScript table I have. I am also using the Tablesorter Filter widget, in order to have several of my columns have drop-down filtering options. I have a new challenge: I am required to add columns to the table dynamically. I have seen this question: [Adding columns dynamically to a table managed with jQuery's tablesorter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710785/adding-columns-dynamically-to-a-table-managed-with-jquerys-tablesorter)  - which recommends that I remove and recreate the table with each addition/removal of a column. This is fair enough, however this causes a conflict with the Filter Widget.

In order to apply the Filter functions, the JavaScript references the column by index only, as so:

```
        widgetOptions: {
            filter_reset: '.reset',
            filter_functions: {
                2: true,
                3: true,
            }
        }
```

This code would cause columns with index 2 and 3 to have the default select Filter. The problem occurs when new columns are added dynamically - the index values of these columns are likely to change.

This brings my question; is there any way to apply widget options to columns named specifically by name? If not, is there some solution I can implement that would achieve the functionality where I can add/remove columns dynamically, without disturbing the filter functions?

Edit: I am also using filter functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update #2: As of [tablesorter v2.17.0](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/wiki/Changes#version-2170-5222014) a class name* or ID can be used to target a column within the `filter_functions` option:

```
// filter functions
widgetOptions: {
    filter_functions : {
        ".exact" : function(e, n, f, i) {
            return e === f;
        }
    }
}
```

* Note: the class name can not include a selector that uses any kind of indexing, e.g. `"th:eq()"`, `":gt()"`, `":lt()"`, `":first"`, `":last"`, `":even"` or `":odd"`, `":first-child"`, `":last-child"`, `":nth-child()"`, `":nth-last-child()"`, etc.

---

In the [docs](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-functions), it shows an alternative to using the `filter_functions` option:

> Alternately, instead of setting the column filter function to true, give the column header a class name of "filter-select". See the [demo](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-custom.html).

So, just add a `filter-select` class name to the column instead.

---

Update: Since other filter functions are being used, you can define these functions outside of the initialization code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/385/))

```
// Add these options to the select dropdown (date example) 
// Note that only the normalized (n) value will contain
// the date as a numerical value (.getTime())
var dateFxns = {

    // Add these options to the select dropdown (date example) 
    // Note that only the normalized (n) value will contain
    // the date as a numerical value (.getTime())
    "< 2004": function (e, n, f, i) {
        return n < Date.UTC(2004, 0, 1); // < Jan 1 2004
    },
    "2004-2006": function (e, n, f, i) {
        return n >= Date.UTC(2004, 0, 1) && // Jan 1 2004
        n < Date.UTC(2007, 0, 1); // Jan 1 2007
    },
    "2006-2008": function (e, n, f, i) {
        return n >= Date.UTC(2006, 0, 1) && // Jan 1 2006
        n < Date.UTC(2009, 0, 1); // Jam 1 2009
    },
    "2008-2010": function (e, n, f, i) {
        return n >= Date.UTC(2008, 0, 1) && // Jan 1 2006
        n < Date.UTC(2011, 0, 1); // Jam 1 2009
    },
    "> 2010": function (e, n, f, i) {
        return n >= Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1); // Jan 1 2010
    }
},
currentDateColumn = 3,
filterFxn = {};
filterFxn[currentDateColumn] = dateFxns;

$('table').tablesorter({
    widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
    widgetOptions: {
        filter_functions: filterFxn
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mottie. This satisfies almost all of my needs. In my question, for simplicity sake, I left out another filter function I have. I have a filter function that defines custom combo box values, as well. Such as:   4: { "> 30 minutes" : function(e,n,f,i) { return n > 30 } etc. I have a variety of these functions. Is there some way I can use class name to reference these columns as well? Thanks.

Comment: Well, that becomes a bit more difficult. Do you know the column index after adding columns?

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer. This does give me an idea, in that instead of referencing a column by number, I could also reference it by id or class name! :P I'll work on adding that in a future version.

Comment: Yes, this should do exactly what I need. When creating the filter functions, I can define them all within the 'filterFxn' variable, which can be dynamically created depending on what index my column of interest will be. If only I could give you more rep :-P

Comment: I forgot to update my answer... referencing a column by class name or id is now possible in most options!